# Is it possible to do location search with DSE Search?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Is it possible to use Solr geospatial search within DSE? We’ve got Solr working for text search, but after following the instructions on the Apache wiki page about enabling geospatial search for fields in Solr’s schema.xml, we're getting an error with the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType. Schema file is solr/conf/schema.xml
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:665)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:294)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.createOrReloadCore(SearchDseToolCommands.java:383)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.access$200(SearchDseToolCommands.java:53)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands$CreateCore.execute(SearchDseToolCommands.java:169)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:114)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:51)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.main(DseTool.java:174)
```

We followed the instruction for implementing a field type with `SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType` on the Solr wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search

Trying to use `LatLonType` instead resulted in the same error.

Comment: You don't specify any information about the software.  What DSE version are you using?  Have you successfully performed any cassandra queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do geospatial with DSE Search.  Here is a github example:

https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-geospatial-demo

Also, some documentation for DSE Spatial:

Example: Analyzing spatial data:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaAnalyzeGIS.html